# C# Form of a form is on separate thread

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading, c#-4.0

I have strange problem.

I have 3 forms.
form1, form2, form3.

form1 is starting/main form.
in form1 I have code:

```
form2 f2 = new form2;
f2.ShowDialog();
```

form2 opens, I can't focus on foorm1, they are both on the same thread. Just what I want.

On form2 I have code:

```
form3 f3 = new form3;
DialogResult result = f3.ShowDialog();
```

I run this code and...
For some, unknown for me reason this form3 runs on new thread and I can focus on form2.
I don't want this to happen. I have no idea why this form3 runs on new thread. I can't use DialogResult because it leads to error (Cross-thread).

It behaves as if I was using f3.Show() but I'm using f3.ShowDialog();

Than you in advance.

P.S.

If i use

```
form3 f3 = new form3;
DialogResult result = f3.ShowDialog(this);
```

I got this:

> System.InvalidOperationException was
>   unhandled by user code
>   Message=Cross-thread operation not
>   valid: Control 'form2' accessed from a
>   thread other than the thread it was
>   created on.

on this line:

```
DialogResult result = f3.ShowDialog(this);
```

Comment: Why do you think they're on separate threads?

Comment: @Conrad Frinx 
This is stupid question. You can display thread number on form and even check number of threads in ProcExplorer

Comment: @Hooch. I'm not the one with the problem.

Comment: @Conrad Frix
Sory but I'm trying to repair that with no luck.

Comment: there's only one UI thread.  If you're debugging, you can keep track of what threads are currently executing code.

Comment: @Hooch. No biggie. Its clear they are indeed on separate threads.

Comment: @Hooch: Conrad's question is not stupid at all. If you actually check (like I just did to be completely positively certain), you will see that the dialog is running in the same thread as the window that it was opened from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dialogs function by implementing their own message loop. Since both threads have a message loop processing messages, you have two dialogs enabled. Either manually disable the first dialog or create and show all dialogs from the same thread. **I would strongly recommend that you do all the UI in a single thread.** Please see the InvokeRequired and Invoke members of Control.

Comment: That's not correct. A dialog does not have it's own message loop, it uses the same message loop as the window that it was opened from. There is only one thread.

Comment: Actually it is correct: It does have its own message loop. How else would the ShowDialog function not return until the dialog is closed? Note I did not say it has its own message QUEUE. The message queue is per-thread. This is even true with Win32 dialogs: See the DialogBox function.

Comment: I'm doing it all in single thread. Function ShowDialog() creats form on the same thread. How to fix this?

Comment: I believe you just said the form3 object was created on a separate thread? The exception you received certainly points to this. What is the full stack trace for the exception?